# Mysql - Get data of different time interval in same query

Tags: mysql

My below query is giving me result of top videos played in past 2 hours, but my requirement is to also get top videos of past 4 hours to past 2 hours, for example if by this query I am getting data from 01:00 PM to 03:00 PM, I also want data from 09:00 AM to 01:00 PM. Can I do this in one query and in efficient way.

Query:

```
select SQL_CACHE channel,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(video_id ORDER BY plays DESC),',', 40) AS video_ids,now() as datetime from
(SELECT channel,video_id,count(video_id) as plays FROM `tbl`
WHERE `datetime_col` > DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR )
and channel != 0
and cat_id != 8
group by channel,video_id
order by channel,plays DESC)x
group by channel;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query with `UNION` to group the results. Also, you can use `BETWEEN` to define the intervals, e.g.

```
select SQL_CACHE channel,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(video_id ORDER BY plays DESC),',', 40) AS video_ids,now() as datetime from
(SELECT channel,video_id,count(video_id) as plays FROM `tbl`
WHERE `datetime_col` BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR ) AND NOW()
and channel != 0
and cat_id != 8
group by channel,video_id
order by channel,plays DESC)x
group by channel

UNION

select SQL_CACHE channel,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(video_id ORDER BY plays DESC),',', 40) AS video_ids,DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR ) as datetime from
(SELECT channel,video_id,count(video_id) as plays FROM `tbl`
WHERE `datetime_col` BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR ) AND DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR )
and channel != 0
and cat_id != 8
group by channel,video_id
order by channel,plays DESC)x
group by channel;
```

Comment: This query will make my original query time double.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Are you talking about the execution time?